# Watir webdriver - Passing variable to multiple tests?

Tags: global-variables, watir-webdriver

I have 50+ Watir test scripts which currently just check a specific URL which is defined inside each of them.

Now we are launching 4 more sites and would like to run these tests on all 5 sites.  To maintain 5 packs of 50+ tests would be a nightmare in the future.

Is there a way I can pass a variable to all of the individual tests with the URL to visit.

For example

```
url = "http://site1.com"
```

That way if we want to then test site 2 we just need to change the url variable and not every single script.

```
url = "http://site2.com"
```

Example test:

```
require "watir-webdriver"

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome

browser.goto "http://url.com/"

browser.text_field(:id, "edit-search").set("Accounting")
browser.button(:value,"Search").click
browser.link(:text, "Accounting Manager with a leading US MNC").click
browser.link(:text, "Apply").click
browser.text_field(:id, "edit-firstname").set("hi2")
browser.text_field(:id, "edit-lastname").set("hi")
browser.text_field(:id, "edit-email").set("t@t.com")
browser.text_field(:id, "edit-current-job").set("Test")
browser.radio(:id, "edit-use-stored").click
browser.radio(:id, "edit-existing-cv-319706").click
browser.text_field(:id, "edit-message").set("Testing")
browser.checkbox(:id, "edit-create-alert").click
browser.button(:value,"Apply").click
browser.screenshot.save '..\screenshots\ApplyWithAlertNonRegistered.png'
browser.link(:text, "Home").click
browser.close
```

Comment: I'm using Watir webdriver which is written in ruby

Comment: Watir-webdriver is simply a library for driving a browser. Usually you would use that within a test framework, which does the test running, reporting, etc. For example, some of the popular Ruby test frameworks are RSpec, Cucumber, MiniTest and Test/Unit.

Comment: Oh nope, just watir webdriver, I'll add a sample test to the question

Comment: Yes they are all separate ruby files, really I'm just asking how to pass a variable in ruby to different ruby scripts

Comment: Sorry, hopefully the last question, but how are you executing each of these scripts? This would help clarify what "passing" options are available.

Comment: At the moment I just have a bat script that calls each one, simple but it works for now.  I don't mind using another method if you have a good suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I would recommend moving to an actual test framework, I think the following approaches would work for your situation.

**Solution 1 - Pass Value From Batch to Test**

In a test script, you can get the parameters passed in from the batch file using the ARGV array.

1. In your batch file, you could define the URL and then pass to the test script as a parameter.

   ```
   SET URL="http://site2.com" 
   ruby test_example1.rb %URL%
   ruby test_example2.rb %URL%
   ```
2. Your tests would get the ARGV[0] value and go to it:

   ```
   browser.goto ARGV[0]
   ```
3. For each test run, you would need to update the batch for the correct url.

**Solution 2 - Specify URL in a Helper File**

An alternative solution would be to specify the url in a variable that is included by each test. This is probably a better approach, especially if there are multiple variables.

1. Create a test_helper.rb file with:

   ```
   url = "http://site1.com"
   ```
2. For each of your test scripts, require this test_helper file and use the url variable:

   ```
   require "watir-webdriver"
   require "test_helper" #(Change path if not in the same folder)
   browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
   browser.goto url
   ```
3. Before each test run, update the test_helper.rb file to point to the correct url.

Comment: Very helpful and with multiple methods, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I like Justin's answer, but another option is [Fig Newton](https://github.com/cheezy/fig_newton). It allows you to change multiple variables depending on the system that you are running on (localhost, on jenkins, UAT, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Justin - in the test_helper file, would it be possible to set the browser type (chrome, ie, or ff) and pass that variable into each test script; so, if I wanted to change the browser, I would only have to change it in the test_helper file rather than having to go into each test script to change?

If possible, how would this look in the test_helper file and test scripts?
test_helper:  type = ff
test script:  browser = Watir::Browser.new :type

Thanks!